# Gitlab CMD command for writing a text inside txtfile using window OS

Tags: gitlab

I'm new in using Git GUI cmd I try many times searching for a command that can write a text inside a Textfile, as a result I found command but not appropriate to use in my OS which is Windows OS. Please if you have an idea about it tell me what to do . Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `echo "foo" > file.txt` do anything for ya? If you're looking for a text _editor_ that's a different matter. Maybe clarify your question. If you're in windows you could always just use notepad.

Comment: Hi @CollinD Thanks for your respond, I try it and its work. Thanks again ^

Comment: but now when I try to write another character the previous text has been override?

Comment: `echo "bar" >> file.txt`: see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php